# Can I handle more than one modalDialog with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, showmodaldialog

I write Selenium test for old application which use ModalDialog windows. I know how to handle with one ModalDialog:

1. Before opening ModalDialog I call this js - to change window pro ModalDialog to classic window:

   `((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript("window.showModalDialog = window.open;");`
2. After opening ModalDialog I switch to that window and I can handle with it:

   ```
   public static void SwitchToWindow(IWebDriver _driver, string url)
   {
       String parentWindowHandle = _driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

       IWebDriver popup = null;
       var windowIterator = _driver.WindowHandles;

       foreach (var windowHandle in windowIterator)
       {
           popup = _driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);

           if (popup.Url.Contains(url))
           {
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

But if I want to do that with second ModalDialog (so I am in third window now) I got this issue:

> threw exception: 
>   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Could not find element by: By.Id: btnClearSearchName

(in Firefox window is flashing: Sending request to, Transfering something, Read something) so it's clear that Selenium cant find element, because the page isn't loaded.

And If I tried to open third window without JS executor before, it shows this error:

> threw exception: 
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7057/hub/session/c7e75043-9605-4f7c-80ac-233803527709/element/%7B7664f1ae-9c42-4de6-9e16-34fede6a9e26%7D/click timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

I use Selenium v3.0.1 with FireFox 45.6.0.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle next window you should switch focus back to default content with

```
_driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Comment: Where should I put it?
Now I in first modal it look like this:
1. change modal to window by JSExecutor
2. click to open the modal (now windows because of 1.)
3. switch to the new window
----
second modal:
- (if I try again JSExecutor  = second modal will not be opened)
- if i dont try JSExecutor and directly open second modalWindow, = timed out error

Comment: I guess you should try to put one before `break;` and one in `else` block

Comment: It does same errors.. with JSExecutor before second window it doesn't open window and flashing requests... without JSExcecutor window can't be handled...